# Grails Database Migration plugin fails silently

Tags: grails, groovy, database-migration

I'm using Grails 3.3.6 (via sdkman) and when I try to use the dbmigration plugin to generate chagelog files it just doesn't do anything and can't figure out how to get more informative output out of the plugin. This is what's on my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.0'
        ...
        runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.46"
    }
}
```

This isn't a new project, I cloned it from a git repo and it is successfully running locally on my machine and several db migrations have been performed before (not on my machine, but the `migrations` folder has dozens of previous migrations, some generated with the plugin it seems). For some reason though, using the db migration plugin from the CLI isn't really working for me even though the project is successfully running locally. This is the output I get after modifying a model class:

```
[user@machine project-root]$ grails dbm-gorm-diff add-field-to-model.groovy --add
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.3.6/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.15.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Usage: 
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web 
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin 


| Available Profiles
--------------------
* angular - A profile for creating Grails applications with Angular 5+
* rest-api - Profile for REST API applications
* base - The base profile extended by other profiles
* angularjs - A profile for creating applications using AngularJS
* plugin - Profile for plugins designed to work across all profiles
* profile - A profile for creating new Grails profiles
* react - A profile for creating Grails applications with a React frontend
* react-webpack - A profile for creating Grails applications with a React frontend using Webpack
* webpack - A profile for creating applications with node-based frontends using webpack 2
* web - Profile for Web applications
* rest-api-plugin - Profile for REST API plugins
* vue - A profile for creating Grails applications with a Vue.js frontend
* web-jboss7 - A Profile for Creating a JBoss 7.1 EAP Project
* web-plugin - Profile for Plugins designed for Web applications

Type 'grails help' or 'grails -h' for more information.
```

From what I've read online that warning is normal for certain versions of grails and/or groovy depending on your jdk version. The point is that the migration groovy script isn't generated as expected. I used variations `grails envname dbm-gorm-diff --add add-field-to-model.groovy`

Comment: Assume you're using java 11 or greater from the warnings, can you try with java 8?

Comment: The error message suggests that the Grails CLI does not recognize the current working directory as a Grails project.

Comment: @MikeW I set up jenv and installed java 8. Now I don't get the warnings but get the same output below it. It doesn't seem to be recognizing the plugin even though it's setup on the gradle file.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I had not refreshed the page before posting my previous comment but yes, your observation is in line with the output I'm getting. How can I get the CLI to recognize it as such? I am in a grails project and I'm able to run it successfully using gradle>application>bootRun so not sure what the issue might be.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm at the project's root folder, should I move to a different one? If so which one?

Comment: "I'm at the project's root folder, should I move to a different one?" - No.  I don't think you are in the wrong directory.  For some reason the CLI seems confused about that.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be recognizing the plugin even though it's setup on the gradle file." - When I add the appropriate dependencies in `buildscript.dependencies {}` and in the app `dependencies` block, I cannot reproduce the problem you are seeing.  If you can identify a combination of factors that triggers that problem, please file a report at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we will investigate.  Best of luck!

Comment: Is it intentional that you are configuring the MySql driver as a `buildscript` dependency?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown regarding `buildscript`: I inherited this project and it is currently in production so I have to assume that it is. What would you suggest? Maybe I can try it out locally.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown for the record, I moved to the `webapp` folder and I did get a different output from running the plugin. It failed in the end because of a swagger import and it could not run successfully but the plugin did attempt to run so it seems the directory had something to do with it?

Comment: @AspiringDev I am sorry that I have not been able to reproduce any of that.  Best of luck!